# How do you Solve an Age-Old Problem?

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction, calculation-puzzle, no-computers

Mansion has a son (Mark) and a daughter (Mindy). Mark is older than Mindy.

Five years ago, Sum of Mark and Mindy’s ages was twenty two. Five years from now, Mark will be exactly twice as old as Mindy.

How old is Mark now? Give your reasoning details.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Let a be Mark and b be Mindy. Then

> $a-5+b-5 = 22$, so $a+b = 32$. Further, $a+5 = 2(b+5) = 2b + 10$. But $a = 32 - b$, so $32 - b + 5 = 37 - b = 2b + 10$. So $3b = 27$, so $b = 9$. Then $a = 32 - 9 = 23$.

So

> Mark is 23.

Answer (score 2):

ma is the age of Mark

my ist the age of Mindy

> 1. (ma-5)+(my-5) = 22  
>  ma-5 + my-5 = 22 |+10  
>  ma+my = 32  
>  2. ma+5 = 2*(my+5)  
>  ma+5 = 2*my+10 |-5  
>  ma = 2*my+5  
>  (2*my+5)+my = 32  
>  3*my + 5 = 32 |-5  
>   3*my = 27 |/3  
>  my = 9  
>  9 + ma = 32 |-9  
>  ma = 23

Comment: Welcome to PSE ! Please use spoilers $$ >! $$ before each line and add 2 spaces at the end of each line. Also try to use MathJax.

Comment: Good answer, but I think I beat you to it!

Comment: Yes you were faster :) , are similar answers in PSE undesirable ?

Comment: @TanteMartina There's some leeway allowed, in cases where one person answers while another's still typing (which happens a lot, let me tell you). If you'd posted your answer seven *hours* after El-Guest, then it would be a problem, but seven minutes seems acceptable to me.

Comment: Tbh, what's more undesirable here is that you're not supposed to answer off-topic questions, because it encouraged people to ask more of them. Again, you have some leeway in that regard, since you only just got here and probably didn't know that, but El-Guest has 23k rep and you'd think he'd know better than that.

Comment: Ok thank you for this information !

Comment: It is undesirable to post comments which don't add or ask anything, see [this](https://puzzling.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/comment). Again, you are new and I have to admit that it can be hard at times to restrain yourself from comments like this but we should try our best to keep the site informative and clean. These types of comments are for the chat rooms. Just wanted to let you know since stackexchange is a unique kind of site and many newcomers don't expect it

Comment: @Adam That comment was fine.  This should be a casual environment, not a super serious one with strict conventions.  Literally go to any question on HNQ's and you'll find comments like that.

Comment: @greenturtle3141 The comment on its own was fine however since they were asking for site advice I thought it would be good to tell them to not get into the habit of responding to everything (not that they would've) while also informing them of the chat feature which is better suited for conversation. My comment was poorly worded, now with your comment and mine I hope there is some extra clarity